# I need to change my filter from single checkbox checked results to multi checkbox checked results in Javascript

Tags: javascript, filter, checkbox

I have a filter running over my content div with use of input `type=checkbox` html tags. The situation is that if I select the checkbox with the color **red**, it only shows the content that contains the red attribute, same with **purple** and **blue**.

However, when I select multiple checkboxes, instead of getting the results of all the selected checkboxes, I get no results at all.

```js
class Object {
  constructor(color, shape, price) {
    this.color = color;
    this.shape = shape;
    this.price = price;
  }
}
const objects = [
  object1 = new Object("purple", "square", "$0"),
  object2 = new Object("purple", "circle", "$20"),
  object3 = new Object("red", "square", "$40"),
  object4 = new Object("red", "circle", "$0"),
  object5 = new Object("blue", "square", "$20"),
  object6 = new Object("blue", "circle", "$40"),
  object7 = new Object("purple", "square", "$60"),
  object8 = new Object("purple", "circle", "$80"),
  object9 = new Object("red", "square", "$100"),
  object10 = new Object("red", "circle", "$60"),
  object11 = new Object("blue", "square", "$80"),
  object12 = new Object("blue", "circle", "$100")
];

let text = "";
objects.forEach(objectLoop);
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = text;

function objectLoop(objects) {
  text += '<p class="object ' + objects.shape + ' ' + objects.color + '">' + objects.price + '</p>';
}

// This is the filter
function change() {
  let results = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".content > p"));
  results.forEach(function(result) {
    result.style.display = "none";
  });

  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".filters input[rel]:checked"), function(input) {
    const attrib = input.getAttribute("rel");
    results = results.filter(function(result) {
      return result.classList.contains(attrib);
    });
  });

  results.forEach(function(result) {
    result.style.display = "block";
  });
}
change();
```

```html
<main class="flex">
  <div class="filters">
    <div class="head">
      <h2>Filters</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <h3>Color:</h3>
      <div class="group flex">
        <label for="">Red:</label>
        <input type="checkbox" rel="red" onchange="change()">
      </div>
      <div class="group flex">
        <label for="">Purple:</label>
        <input type="checkbox" rel="purple" onchange="change()">
      </div>
      <div class="group flex">
        <label for="">Blue:</label>
        <input type="checkbox" rel="blue" onchange="change()">
      </div>
      <button>Reset filters</button>
    </div>
    <div class="foot"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="objects">
    <div class="head">
      <h2>Objects</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="content flex" id="content"></div>
    <div class="foot"></div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

it seems that in your code when multiple checkboxes are selected, your filtering logic is wrong. You're filtering the results array separately for each checked checkbox, which leads to an intersection of results, meaning you only get the items that satisfy all selected checkboxes, which is likely not what you intend.

You need to adjust your `change()` function to keep the items that satisfy any of the selected checkboxes, not all of them

```js
class Object {
  constructor(color, shape, price) {
    this.color = color;
    this.shape = shape;
    this.price = price;
  }
}
const objects = [
  object1 = new Object("purple", "square", "$0"),
  object2 = new Object("purple", "circle", "$20"),
  object3 = new Object("red", "square", "$40"),
  object4 = new Object("red", "circle", "$0"),
  object5 = new Object("blue", "square", "$20"),
  object6 = new Object("blue", "circle", "$40"),
  object7 = new Object("purple", "square", "$60"),
  object8 = new Object("purple", "circle", "$80"),
  object9 = new Object("red", "square", "$100"),
  object10 = new Object("red", "circle", "$60"),
  object11 = new Object("blue", "square", "$80"),
  object12 = new Object("blue", "circle", "$100")
];

let text = "";
objects.forEach(objectLoop);
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = text;

function objectLoop(objects) {
  text += '<p class="object ' + objects.shape + ' ' + objects.color + '">' + objects.price + '</p>';
}

// This is the filter
function change() {
  let results = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".content > p"));
  results.forEach(function(result) {
    result.style.display = "none";
  });

  const checkedBoxes = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".filters input[rel]:checked"))
    .map(input => input.getAttribute("rel"));

  if (checkedBoxes.length === 0) {
    // If no checkboxes are checked, display all results
    results.forEach(function(result) {
      result.style.display = "block";
    });
  } else {
    results.forEach(function(result) {
      const classes = result.className.split(" ");
      if (checkedBoxes.some(box => classes.includes(box))) {
        result.style.display = "block";
      }
    });
  }
}
change();
```

```html
<main class="flex">
  <div class="filters">
    <div class="head">
      <h2>Filters</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <h3>Color:</h3>
      <div class="group flex">
        <label for="">Red:</label>
        <input type="checkbox" rel="red" onchange="change()">
      </div>
      <div class="group flex">
        <label for="">Purple:</label>
        <input type="checkbox" rel="purple" onchange="change()">
      </div>
      <div class="group flex">
        <label for="">Blue:</label>
        <input type="checkbox" rel="blue" onchange="change()">
      </div>
      <button>Reset filters</button>
    </div>
    <div class="foot"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="objects">
    <div class="head">
      <h2>Objects</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="content flex" id="content"></div>
    <div class="foot"></div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: You're a lifesaver! This works! I was having major issues with this part for days. Thank you so much!